# In Multi-Tenant Data Architecture, what is the best way to implement tenant filter view?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, saas, multi-tenant

I am implementing a SaaS application using ASP.Net MVC 2 and SQL Server database. I am using Shared Tenancy approach.

To filter data, so far I have found 2 approaches.

Option 1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_tvf

Using sql login per tenant. Thus, using SUSER_SID() as a filter in the views

Option 2: http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/jyoung/archive/2010/03/22/845.aspx

Storing tenant id in the Context_Info. Thus, using a sql function that reads tenant id from the Context_Info as a filter in the views.

Can you please help me pick the appropriate option?

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this comes down to a battle of security models. A DBA may insist you do the former. I, being more pragmatic, would likely pass the tenant ID into my SPs or queries from the application layer.

I would back this up with a whole lot of unit tests that ensure one tenant can never see another tenants data, and I would only store the current tenant on the server in session or simmilar, never in a cookie or in URLs, or anywhere else that can be hacked on the client.

This makes it much easier to add new tenants, as there is no DB config required.

Of course, sessions can be hacked, so you need to take all precautions to ensure that however you store tenant ID on the server, it is immune from spoofs, etc.

Comment: I'm with you on this one: option 1 isn't very flexible because it's based on the assumption that each user will exist at the domain level. Option 2 lets you have users who exist only as rows in some User table. This lets you fill the user table by syncing with the AD of that tenant's domain.

Comment: The option to store tenant Id in session was not in my radar, so can you please elaborate on how to implement it?

I am going to map tenant site URL to a tenant id.

In which tier, do you set the tenant id session? Would you store it in application cache? 

Thanks

Comment: I am thinking of this as a standard web site: user logs in, you then grab their tenant ID and redirect to that tenants home page. Although it is fine to use tenant ID in URL, you need to confirm user is *allowed* to access that tenanID on each request, and a simple way to do that is keep the tenantID in session (`Session["TenantID"] = user.TenantID`) so that you don't have to query the DB for the user's profile on each request. I would probably put code in my base Controller class that confirms that the user is allowed to access the TenantID in the querystring; if not, it redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will use tenant id in session.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that inline table-valued functions can also be useful in building any isolation layers.